# Cycle a decimal digit by 1 in c#

Tags: c#, math

I'd like to cycle a decimal digit by 1 using a single operation of possible.

```
if x is 0 - 8 then x = x + 1
if x is 9 then x = 0
```

or the opposite

```
if x is 1 - 9 then x = x - 1
if x is 0 then x = 9
```

Is there a way to do this with C# in one line of code?  If not C# are there any other languages that could?

What if I wanted to cycle it by more than one (2 or 3 or whatever)?

Comment: _"in one line of code"_ - why?

Comment: @CodeCaster: It's one-liner day today.

Comment: @CodeCaster to make my code look a little nicer or maybe to learn something new about the language or math or the compiler.

Comment: By the way, what's wrong with my question?  Why the downvotes?

Comment: It's not clear whether you mean the last digit, or a digit passed into the function. And why in one line, that just seems like "I want it in one line to look cool"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
var y = (x + 1) % 10;
```

This gives:

```
x    y
------
0    1
1    2
...
8    9
9    0
```

To decrement

```
var y = (i + 9) % 10;
```

Obviously to change the amount, just change `1` or `9` respectively

Comment: Yeah, I came up with that one as well.  Been looking for a way to do the -1 direction now.

Comment: Use (x+9)%10 for the -1 direction.

Comment: @Trenin Yep - just figured that - will update answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int Cycle(int x)
{
    return x+1 % 10;
}
```

---

```
int result = Cycle(0); // result is 1
int result = Cycle(8); // result is 9
int result = Cycle(9); // result is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int Cycle(int x, int by = 1)
{
    return (x+by) % 10;
}
```

now you can call `Cycle(9, 3)` which should give you `2`

Comment: This is the best answer imo